# TestNG: Can you use custom Junit Runners?

Tags: java, junit, testng

Can you use a custom junit runner when you run junit tests in TestNG? I thought that the org.junit.runner.JUnitCore that TestNG ran would be able to notice my @Runwith(customRunner.class) annotation and use the appropriate runner for the test. Can anyone confirm if TestNG does or doesn't have support for junit tests with @Runwith(customRunner.class)? Is there a way for my team to let TestNG know that it's okay to use a custom junit runner?

I tried to do the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite_name">    
    <test name="test_name" junit="true">
        <classes>
           <class name="class.name.of.test" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

In my suite file, I have the following

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="all_tests">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="testng_tests.xml">
        <suite-file path="junit_tests.xml">
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

But I seem to get really odd errors when I use @Runwith within my junit tests.

```
@RunWith(RestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("provider")
@PactBroker(host = "someip", port="someport")
public class PactContractTest {

    @TestTarget
    public final HttpTarget target = new HttpTarget(...);

    @State("some state")
    public void guaranteeSomeState(){

    }
}
```

I receive this error:

```
Method 'some super long contract description' 
not found in class 'the.actual.proper.class': 
the.actual.proper.class.some super long contract description()
```

It seems clear to me that something is amiss, and I'm thinking that the customRunner isn't running.

Comment: Could you try with the latest TestNG version (6.11 or 6.12)? Could you share `the.actual.proper.class`?

Comment: Thanks!  

Using the latest TestNG resolved my error issue. My tests seem to be running(the requests are going through). However, now I'm getting a 0 tests ran, 0 tests passed, 0 tests skipped. But this is a lot better.

The below is a description of my previous error.
The "the.actual.proper.class" is the package name for where the junit test lives. The "some super long contract description()" is a misread method name that comes from a description field from the test that I'm running.